# Проблема с отображение компонента звездного рейтинга Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, star-rating

Доюрый день.
Использую следующий компонент: [Star Rating Component](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-and-highly-customisable-star-rating-component-for-vue/).
Натолкнулся на две пробелмы.
Первая: если использовать данный компонент на темном фоне, то, у звезд появляется белая граница(заметно при увеличение, и без него), может это можно исправить если влезть в svg ? (Не представляю себе возможным, что можно сделать
Вторая: можно ли сделать из 5 звезд десятиабльную шкалу измерения, где одна звезда равна 2, а 1 это половина звезды.

Или для данной задачи использовать другой компонент?

```js
Vue.component('star-rating', VueStarRating.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    setRating: function(rating) {
      this.rating = "You have Selected: " + rating + " stars";
    },
    showCurrentRating: function(rating) {
      this.currentRating = (rating === 0) ? this.currentSelectedRating : "Click to select " + rating + " stars"
    },
    setCurrentSelectedRating: function(rating) {
      this.currentSelectedRating = "You have Selected: " + rating + " stars";
    }
  },
  data: {
    rating: "No Rating Selected",
    currentRating: "No Rating",
    currentSelectedRating: "No Current Rating",
    boundRating: 3,
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.custom-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

.vue-star-rating-rating-text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-star-rating@1.6.0/dist/star-rating.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Рейтинг</h2>
  <star-rating :increment="0.5" :border-width="2" border-color="#ffd055"></star-rating>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на счте белой границы - непонятно. Там в стилях стоит значение stroke-width: 0. Это значит, что никаких "границ" нет.
На счет значения рейтинга, можно сделать как-то так

```js
Vue.component('star-rating', VueStarRating.default)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  computed: {
     computedRating(){
       return this.value* 2;
     },
  },
  methods: {
    handlerSelected(e){
      this.value  = e
    },
    setRating: function(rating) {
      this.rating = "You have Selected: " + rating + " stars";
    },
    showCurrentRating: function(rating) {
      this.currentRating = (rating === 0) ? this.currentSelectedRating : "Click to select " + rating + " stars"
    },
    setCurrentSelectedRating: function(rating) {
      this.currentSelectedRating = "You have Selected: " + rating + " stars";
    }
  },
  data: {
    rating: "No Rating Selected",
    currentRating: "No Rating",
    currentSelectedRating: "No Current Rating",
    boundRating: 3,
    value: 0,
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
}

.custom-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

h2{
color:#fff;
}
.vue-star-rating-rating-text{
color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-star-rating@1.6.0/dist/star-rating.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Рейтинг</h2>

  <star-rating @rating-selected="handlerSelected" :show-rating="false" :increment="0.5"></star-rating>
<h3 :style="{color: 'white'}">{{computedRating}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Появилась идея для костыля, можно добавить границу, и покрасить её в желтый цвет, правда будет смотреться не очень красиво, обновил код в вопросе.
Спасибо за ваш ответ!